# Why did El Chivo decide not to carry out the hit job?

Tags: amores-perros

Before Chivo "adopted" Cofi (the black fighting dog) in *Amores Perros*, it seemed like he fully intended to carry out the hit job.

He then "adopted" Cofi; and Cofi killed all his other dogs. It seems like this was somehow the trigger/epiphany for him to *not* carry out the hit job. But I can't figure out why this makes any sense.

So my question: Why did Chivo decide instead to kidnap his hit target (instead of being, as usual, a professional and just murdering him on the spot)?

Answer (score 1):

ref: [Amores Perros (2000): Plot Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2016/10/10/Amores-Perros-2000-Plot-Explained)

> After the accident, Cofi is with El Chivo. Had it been any other dog,
>   it wouldn’t have changed Chivo’s life. But Cofi turns out to be a
>   killer and kills all the other dogs. While initially Chivo is overcome
>   with rage and wants to kill Cofi, he realizes that he too is a killer
>   and murders people for money. The pain he feels when he loses his dogs
>   makes him realize the pain he has caused to several others. He, as a
>   result, doesn’t kill his target. He leaves it to his client and target
>   to make their own decision.

In fact, if not for the accident, El Chivo would have killed his target. But due to the commotion, he's forced to abort. Guess the only loved ones in his life were his dogs, when they get killed he realizes the meaning of "taking a life".